# Get text of label element on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an unordered list and under each `<li>` element I have a `<label>` and a link to get the text of `<label>`.

For example, if I click on first "Copy Text" link, I want to get "label1" and for second one I want "label2".

I have come up with below code, but its not working. Can anyone please help me to fix this.

**HTML Code :**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>label1</label>
        <a onclick="copyText()">Copy Text</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>label2</label>
        <a onclick="copyText()">Copy Text</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS Code :**

```
function copyText() {
    alert($(this).closest('li').children('label').text());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the context of the element, and change `Text` to `.text()`.

```
onclick="copyText(this)"
```

```
function copyText(el) {
    alert($(el).closest('li').children('label').text());
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vkkjudg7/)

---

You could just avoid jQuery and get the element's text directly:

```
function copyText(el) {
    alert(el.previousSibling.textContent);
}
```

---

I'd suggest using unobtrusive JavaScript and adding event listeners instead:

```
$('li a').on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).closest('li').find('label').text());
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/82Lu1mt1/)